# Como guardar información de richTextBox en strings con delimitador?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Hola a tod@s llevo horas rompiendome la cabeza y buscando información y no encuentro nada que me ayude.

Tengo un richTextBox con información y quiero guardarla en strings y indicar que cuando hay un salto de linea guardarlo en otro string o meterlo en una lista de strings o algo de este tipo que yo lo tenga "numerado".

Sacar el texto con un delimitador, que sería el salto de linea `\n`

No proporciono codigo por que no tengo nada, nada de lo que he echo a servido de nada.
Alguien puede proporcionarme algo de luz en el asunto? muchas gracias.

```
string linea1 = richTextBox1.Lines.GetValue(0).ToString();
```

Esto es lo unico que he sabido hacer, he de decir que no tengo mucha experiencia.

```
string texto = richTextBox1.Text;
var array = texto.Split(new[] { "\n\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
richTextBox2.Text = array[2];
```

Y lo he solucionado, lo dejo por aquí por si ha alguien puede servirle, gracias.

Comment: Cual es la pregunta? porque la forma de resolverlo es con un split...

Comment: Ya está solucionado , gracias.

Comment: Entonces eliminamos la pregunta? la cerramos?

Comment: porque la pregunta no tiene una pregunta.. y la respuesta debe ir donde dice respuesas...